# "Failed to read TLS record (2)" connecting to office365 IMAP using Chilcat ActiveX

Tags: office365, imap

We used to have internal Exchange and connection worked. Now the Exchange server is migrated to Office365 cloud, and I cannot connect.

```
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @imap, 'SslProtocol', 'TLS 1.2 or higher'
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @imap, 'Ssl', '1'
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @imap, 'Port', '993'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @imap, 'Connect', @success OUT, 'outlook.office365.com'
```

Error text:

```
ChilkatLog:
  Connect_Imap:
    DllDate: Jul 24 2019
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.79
    UnlockPrefix: THOMASIMAPMAILQ
    Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit
    Language: ActiveX / x64
    VerboseLogging: 0
    connectInner:
      connectToImapServer:
        hostname: outlook.office365.com
        port: 993
        socket2Connect:
          connect2:
            connectImplicitSsl:
              clientHandshake:
                clientHandshake2:
                  readHandshakeMessages:
                    Failed to read TLS record (2)
                    tlsRec_msg: 0
                    msgLen: 29298
                    nReadNBytes: 0
                    status: 0
                  --readHandshakeMessages
                --clientHandshake2
              --clientHandshake
              Client handshake failed. (3)
            --connectImplicitSsl
            ConnectFailReason: 103
          --connect2
        --socket2Connect
        failReason: 0
      --connectToImapServer
      connect failed.
    --connectInner
    Failed.
  --Connect_Imap
--ChilkatLog
```

It seems that the first handshake is OK, but the second fails.
Any ideas?

Comment: `Failed to read TLS record (2)  tlsRec_msg: 0 msgLen: 29298 nReadNBytes: 0` doesn't sound as if you're receiving anything at all. Look for a firewall issue.

Comment: wrong port? with starttls it should 587.